# Provide type variable value for another constructor

Tags: java, generics

I have this class:

```
public class Test<T> {
    public Test() {
        this(() -> true); // error here
    }

    public Test(Supplier<T> c) {
    }
}
```

Compilation fails with this error:

```
Error:(23, 24) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    boolean cannot be converted to T
```

The only workaround I found is using a static factory method:

```
public static Test<Boolean> makeDefault() {
    return new Test<>(() -> true);
}
```

Is there any way for a constructor, that does not contain some type variable, to call another one, which does? Why this limitation?

**EDIT:**
My usecase: I have a class with optional `keyExtractor`. Key type is one of the type parameters. If the user does not provide a `keyExtractor`, I use just one that returns any constant not-null value.

Comment: The type variable does not belong to the constructor. It belongs to the type (at an instance context).

Comment: Edit my answer to fix terminology. But why does it not compile?

Comment: I found a workaround: to cast to raw type: `this((Supplier) () -> true);`. But why?

Comment: How do you know clients of this class meant to use `Boolean`? Why is the class generic in the first place?

Comment: For those, who use the other constructor.

Comment: The question is kind of pointless without context about what you plan to do with the `Supplier`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: take it as abstract or theoretical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *make it compile*, you can do a cast to raw type:

```
public class Test<T> {
    public Test() {
        this((Supplier) () -> true);
    }

    public Test(Supplier<T> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

This has the drawback, that if the user provides incorrect type parameter when calling the constructor, he might get unexpected `ClassCastException`:

```
Test<Integer> t = new Test<>();
System.out.println(t.supplier().get()); // prints "true"
```

Better way would be to use static factory method, that will clearly state the `Supplier` type to the user:

```
public class Test<T> {
    public static Test<Boolean> newWithConstantSupplier() {
        return new Test<>(() -> true);
    }

    public Test(Supplier<T> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

In my case, I ended up removing the `T` parameter and take `Supplier<?>`, as I have no method in public API, that exposed the `T` type, so there's no point for the user to have it in the first place:

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
        this((Supplier) () -> true);
    }

    public Test(Supplier<?> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you were to write:

```
Test<String> t = new Test<>();
```

That results in the other constructor being called; effectively:

```
Test<String> t = new Test<String>(() -> true);
```

but this isn't type correct: `() -> true` doesn't supply a `String`, it supplies a `Boolean` (or `Serializable`, or `Object`).

If you want to provide a default constructor like this, 
you need to return a value which can be cast to anything: the only such value is `null`:

```
this(() -> null);
```

Alternatively, remove the default constructor, and provide a no-arg factory method:

```
static Test<Boolean> createInstance() {
  return new Test<>(() -> true);
}
```